# How do I use another gem as a dependency and create a class that inherits from it

Tags: ruby, rubygems, apiblueprint

I'm trying to create a gem, that wraps some external API calls, and I want to use a gem called 'api-blueprint'

I already added as a dependency on my gemspec file
`spec.add_runtime_dependency 'api-blueprint'`.

and now I want some of my classes to inherit from it

```
module MyGem
  class Request < ApiBlueprint::Model
    ... code ...
  end
end
```

And I get an error

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant MyGem::ApiBlueprint
```

And I'm not sure how can I inherit from a dependency without appending my gem name to the namespace. I also tried without wrapping it inside a module, but I get the same issue, albeit without `MyGem` namespace.

I used this gem inside a rails app, with the same use without problems, but now I need to refactor that logic out of the rails app into a gem.

I also tried to require both as `api_blueprint` and `api-blueprint` the latter returning this error

```
Failure/Error: require "api-blueprint"

ArgumentError:
  wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
```

and the former just returning a LoadError.
I'm not sure what seems to be the issue here, do I need to include elsewhere besides the gemspec file? Note that I also use `spec.add_dependency` but I got the same issues. I'm a bit lost here, this is my first go at a rubygem

Thanks for the attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I'm not sure how can I inherit from a dependency without appending my gem name to the namespace.

You don't need to do that. You're just being confused by a misleading error message.

In ruby, constant lookups are first attempted inside the module and *then* in the global namespace.

So in other words, this code:

```
module MyGem
  class Request < ApiBlueprint::Model
```

is *first* trying to find the constant: `MyGem::ApiBlueprint::Model`, and (if that fails), it *then* tries to find the constant: `ApiBlueprint::Model`. If that fails too, it uses the first error message, which is what you're seeing.

To prevent the confusing error message (although this alone won't fix the actual  problem!!), you can explicitly tell the interpreter to **only** look for the constant in the global namespace:

```
module MyGem
  class Request < ::ApiBlueprint::Model
```

---

> ```
> Failure/Error: require "api-blueprint"
>
> ArgumentError:
>   wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
> ```

You'll need to give us more context on that error. What's the stack trace? What method is being called with 2 arguments instead of 0?

As far as I can tell, adding this require statement *should* be all you need to do.

Comment: You're right, I was digging and the issue was with the dependencies versions, I somehow installed a more recent version that broke and caused the argument error. This was not visible to me while I was running the specs. Thanks!

Comment: needless to say, I feel so dumb for opening a question and the issue was something else (: